# Difference between *(.data), *(.data*) and *(.data.*) in linker script

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

Just curious to know what is the difference between such constructions (for **text**, **data**, **rodata**, **bss** etc) in linker script:

```
.data :
{
    *(.data)
}


.data :
{
    *(.data*)
}


.data :
{
    *(.data.*)
}
```

In all cases we gather **data** sections from all object files, but the devil is in the detail.

Fast test showed that addresses in *map* file differ and in turn it influences the size of executable file.

I tried to find the information in **ld** [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.27/ld/index.html) but found nothing (or just missed it).

I guess that it should be something very simple (so called *obvious*).

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In any place where you may use a specific file or section name, you may also use a wildcard pattern.

It works like a regular pattern

- `*(.data)` - .data sections, *Example:*  `.data`
- `*(.data*)`- .data* section, *Example:* `.dataTEST`
- `*(.data.*)` - .data.* section, *Example:* `.data.TEST`

[Find more info here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.27/ld/Input-Section-Wildcards.html#Input-Section-Wildcards)

Comment: I suppose next question should be how to read documentation properly)). Thanks a lot.