# Difference between *(.text) and *(.text*) in linker scripts

Tags: compilation, linker

In linker scripts, `*(.text)` means that all text section in all input files, but what does exactly `*(.text*)` mean? I couldn't find it in GNU linker documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`*(.text*)` means all section names matching wildcard `.text*` in all files. So if a file contains some special section `.textTEST`, it will include that too as `*` matches that. This link pointed by other answer has correct explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40807331/15239054, but the explanation by https://stackoverflow.com/a/58190997/15239054 is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer to this is the same as the answer to this question:

[Difference between *(.data), *(.data*) and *(.data.*) in linker script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786942/difference-between-data-data-and-data-in-linker-script)

---

The `*` symbol is a wildcard pattern, it will match any file name.

`*(.text)` will match any file with the suffix ".text", `*(.text*)` will match any file name containing ".text" anywhere in its name.

Wildcard documentation: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.27/ld/Input-Section-Wildcards.html#Input-Section-Wildcards